# Questionable typecheck script result of some michelson code

Tags: tezos-client, michelson, type-checker

I've tried to type check create_contract.tz in mini_scenarios and had the following result.  It is well-typed, but I'm wondering if the occurrence of the last comment `/* [ pair (list operation) (string @parameter) ] */` is an intended behavior of tezos-client typecheck script?  If so, what is this type for?

I tried in a sandboxed mode of the latest master branch (5b919792).

```
{ parameter (option address) ;
  storage unit ;
  code { /* [ pair (option @parameter address) (unit @storage) ] */
         CAR
         /* [ list operation : @parameter string ] */ ;
         IF_NONE
           { /* [] */
             PUSH string "dummy"
             /* [ string ] */ ;
             PUSH mutez 100000000
             /* [ mutez : string ] */ ;
             NONE key_hash
             /* [ option key_hash : mutez : string ] */ ;
             CREATE_CONTRACT
               { parameter string ;
                 storage string ;
                 code { CAR ; NIL operation ; PAIR } }
             /* [ operation : address ] */ ;
             DIP { /* [ address ] */
                   SOME
                   /* [ option address ] */ ;
                   DIP { /* [] */
                         SELF
                         /* [ @self contract (option address) ] */ ;
                         PUSH mutez 0
                         /* [ mutez : @self contract (option address) ] */ }
                   /* [ option address : mutez : @self contract (option address) ] */ ;
                   TRANSFER_TOKENS
                   /* [ operation ] */ ;
                   NIL operation
                   /* [ list operation : operation ] */ ;
                   SWAP
                   /* [ operation : list operation ] */ ;
                   CONS
                   /* [ list operation ] */ }
             /* [ operation : list operation ] */ ;
             CONS
             /* [ list operation ] */ ;
             UNIT
             /* [ unit : list operation ] */ ;
             SWAP
             /* [ list operation : unit ] */ ;
             PAIR
             /* [ pair (list operation) unit ] */ }
           { /* [ @parameter.some address ] */
             SELF
             /* [ @self contract (option address) : @parameter.some address ] */ ;
             ADDRESS
             /* [ @self.address address : @parameter.some address ] */ ;
             SENDER
             /* [ @sender address : @self.address address : @parameter.some address ] */ ;
             IFCMPNEQ
               { FAIL }
               { /* [ @parameter.some address ] */ }
             /* [ @parameter.some address ] */ ;
             CONTRACT string
             /* [ @parameter.some.contract option (contract string) ] */ ;
             IF_SOME
               { /* [ @parameter.some.contract.some contract string ] */ }
               { FAIL }
             /* [ @parameter.some.contract.some contract string ] */ ;
             PUSH mutez 0
             /* [ mutez : @parameter.some.contract.some contract string ] */ ;
             PUSH string
                  "abcdefg"
             /* [ string : mutez : @parameter.some.contract.some contract string ] */ ;
             TRANSFER_TOKENS
             /* [ operation ] */ ;
             NIL operation
             /* [ list operation : operation ] */ ;
             SWAP
             /* [ operation : list operation ] */ ;
             CONS
             /* [ list operation ] */ ;
             UNIT
             /* [ unit : list operation ] */ ;
             SWAP
             /* [ list operation : unit ] */ ;
             PAIR
             /* [ pair (list operation) unit ] */ } }
  /* [ pair (list operation) (string @parameter) ] */ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have visibly found a bug in the client typechecking command. Don't hesitate to open an issue for it on https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos. I bet that the client is confused by the storage type of the inner script (`{ parameter string ; storage string ; code { CAR ; NIL operation ; PAIR } }`).